# Using Python readline() to get multiple sensor data over USB from Arduino Uno

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry pi 3B+ hooked up to an Arduino Uno via a USB cable and am receiving multiple sensor data.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to separate those out in python.  Like if I get data like:

27.3

0

1

It needs to know the first line is temperature, the second line is motion detection, and the third line is noise detection and so on...

Idea 1)
Have the sensors all update at the same time in the same order.  Code it in a loop so the first readline() saves to temperature variable, second line saves to motion variable, and so on until it loops back around...

Idea 2)
Put some kind of flag in front of each sensor data and have python read each line and decide what to do with it. Like temperature would be output like t27.3 and the code in python would see the t in front and know to take the rest of the data and update it to the server.  I'm not sure offhand how the code for that would look though

Which would be the better(ideally faster) approach?  If the second one, can you point me to some code for parsing strings? Its been a while since I've had to do that, I have completely forgotten. Thanks!

Comment: both ways are possible and speed should not be any issue. the rest can be found online with ease

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is use a data format which is future proof so lets use a simple JSON.
 
Its standarized, phyton has built in support and on Arfuino we can code by hand without huge libs 
So here two snippets ready to use for your momentary need. Feel free to adapt as you like and read the comments inthe code to learn more about the used functions

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import serial
import time
import json

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

buffer = ""

while True:
    try:
            buffer = ser.readline()
            print buffer
            data = json.loads(buffer)
            print data["temperature"]
            temperature = data["temperature"]
            print temperature
            print data["motion "]
            motion  = data["motion "]
            print motion 
            print data["noise"]
            noise = data["noise"]
            print noise

            buffer = ""
            print " "
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print "Error : try to parse an incomplete message"
```

On the Arduino side we use a global char array to build our JSON

```
 char jsonData[256] = {'\0'}; /* Defined globally choose size large enough */
 char numBuffer[16] = {'\0'}; /* Defined globally used for convering numbers to string */

// here we build the JSON

strcpy (jsonData, "{\"temperature\":\"" );
    // If its an int use this command
    //  itoa(temperature, numBuffer, 10); // convert int DATA from sensors etc.
    // For float we use this command    
    // dtostrf(floatvar, StringLengthIncDecimalPoint, numVarsAfterDecimal, charbuf);
dtostrf(temperature, 3, 2, numBuffer); // -> xx.xx
 strcat(jsonData, numBuffer);
 strcat (jsonData, "\",\"motion\":\"" );
 itoa(motion, numBuffer, 10); // convert int DATA from sensors etc.
 strcat(jsonData, numBuffer);
 strcat (jsonData, "\",\"noise\":\"" );
 itoa(noise, numBuffer, 10); // convert int DATA from sensors etc.
 strcat(jsonData, numBuffer);
 strcat (jsonData, "\"}");  

 // The JSON data looks like: {"temperature":"21.50","motion":"113","noise":"321"}
 Serial.println(jsonData);
```

Do not forget to set the same serial speed on both machines (in the SW) and an initiation from one side to ensure complete transmission of the JSON